# E-Learning Web Authoring

Tags: microsoft-office, authoring, libreoffice

The company I work for creates online courses for operation and maintenance of various equipment. Currently, we write the courses in Word. We have an XML schema that is applied to the document. The XML schema allows us to tag pages, questions (multi-choice, multi-answer), flash content, etc. We have a translator program created for us that takes the information from the Word XML file and converts it to a web site.

My problem is, new versions of Microsoft Word do not allow you to put in XML tags from a schema. I want to stay using Word or other Word Processors because it is quick and easy to use for the writers. I have been looking at various programs such as LibreOffice and different options in Word. What can I do to take content from these programs and author it on the web and still be able to have things like test questions or Flash content?

Comment: +1. Good question. I believe you can indeed apply schemas to newer versions of Word, it's just done differently than 2003. However, you could also consider Building Blocks and Custom XML Parts for SCORM tagging - I did this for the company I used to work for. (We created multi-output courses for both e-Learning and short classroom deliveries on the same subject, outputting our course in Word to both PPT and HTML).

Comment: Very good question, would love to hear if you made any progress on this

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? Have you tried the Word "Save As" functions for document types of Word 97-2003 or XML?